# Как использовать микрофон и камеру в Qemu?

Tags: linux, kvm, qemu, виртуальная-машина

Я использую Artix Linux и использую Qemu и KVM для эмуляции Windows 10. Мне нужно включить поддержку моего микрофона и веб-камеры USB. Я попытался сначала передать веб-камеру через Virtmanager, моя виртуальная машина видит веб-камеру, но я не могу получить видеопоток. Также я не могу получить звук в моей виртуальной машине из микрофона. Пробовал запустить с консоли:
`sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 4096 -rtc base=localtime  -hda /path/win10.qcow2 -cpu host -device hda-duplex -device usb-host, hostbus=<n>, hostaddr=<m>, id=<id>`
Появляется эта ошибка:
`drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin иначе вопрос может быть закрыт. Я тревогу поставил уже

Comment: ну, дык, `hostbus`/`hostaddr` то правильные? и пробелы лишние только здесь или в командной строке тоже?

Comment: Да, я использовал адреса через lsusb.